# Sqlite sum of every line

Tags: php, sqlite, math

I have a database which print me all employees of countries.

```
 |Year|Country1|Country2|Country3|Country4|All
```

This is table, only with 25 countries and year from 2000 to now.
In Internet I found only information for sum(country4) for example,
but how can use sum with all fields exclude Year and All.

**Updated:**

```
 Year | ZA | NA | BW | MG | ZW | AO | ZM | KE | NG | CF | GH | CM | CD | ET | UG | EG | DZ | MA | MR | NE | SD | TN | SO | All 
------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----
 2000 | 10 | 10 |  5 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 0  | 0  |  0 |  25  
 2001 | 25 | 10 |  8 |  5 |  5 |  9 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 0  | 0  |  0 |  62
```

This is database and I need the sum from ZA to SO without `year` and `All`. `All` is the result of the sum, but I think SQLite or PHP can build sum without me doing it manually?

When I search in internet I found only example for sum of one column but not for rows.

Comment: `SELECT country, sum(*) FROM employees GROUP BY country` A general database schema would help.

Comment: If the `All` column is the sum of all the `CountryX` columns, why not just sum this?

Comment: SELECT country, sum(*) FROM ... will not work, for Country I use the iso codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 'sum a row' you simply add the relevant fields together:

```
select
  ZA+NA+BW+MG+ZW+AO+ZM+KE+NG+CF+GH+CM+CD+ET+UG+EG+DZ+MA+MR+NE+SD+TN+SO
from
  table_name
```

That results in (from your test data) two rows:

```
25
62
```

If you want to get the sum of those values just wrap the addition in a `sum`:

```
sum(ZA+NA+BW+MG+ZW+AO+ZM+KE+NG+CF+GH+CM+CD+ET+UG+EG+DZ+MA+MR+NE+SD+TN+SO)
```

Result:

```
87
```

Answer (score 0):

```
|Year|ZA|NA|BW|MG|ZW|AO|ZM|KE|NG|CF|GH|CM|CD|ET|UG|EG|DZ|MA|MR|NE|SD|TN|SO|All|
    |2000|10|10|5|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|25|
    |2001|25|10|8|5|5|9|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|62|
```

This is database and I need the sum from ZA to SO without year and All. All is the result of the sum, but i think sqlite or php can build sum without I do it manually or?

When I search in internet i found only example for sum of one column but not for rows.

Thank you

Silvio